# Who were the ten staff members behind Kemono Friends?

Tags: kemono-friends

One claim commonly made about *Kemono Friends* is that it was created by "a staff of 10 over 500 days." (This seems to source ultimately to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/potato607/status/846769599475412992).) Some people mention further that five of the ten were animators, but I don't have a source for that part.

Who were these ten staff members who created *Kemono Friends*?

<sup>The Anime News Network [encyclopedia entry](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=18799) for the show offers six names. That's a start. If "five animators" is correct, presumably the missing four all shared that title, working under Animation Director Yoshihisa Isa.</sup>

Comment: I don't have the rep to create a kemono-friends tag. I would've if I could've.

Comment: No problem, I've done it for you.

Comment: I seem to recall more than 10 names in the credits.

Comment: The image attached to the tweet mentioned "10 animation production staffs" instead of "10 generic staffs". The "animation production" is by [Yaoyorozu](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=13150), though no clue on the number of staffs working on it. However, there are 10 names mentioned as "producer" on [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%91%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BA_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)#.E3.82.B9.E3.82.BF.E3.83.83.E3.83.95)... I don't know if it's related or not though.